# hql insert query with parameter

Tags: hql

```
Query query = s.createQuery("insert into Paymentinfo(appointid, appointfees, status, pid) values=(?,?,?,?)");
query.setParameter(0, totalBooks);
query.setParameter(1, ml.getFees()); 
query.setParameter(2, "Pending");
query.setParameter(3, ml.getPid());
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: HQL does not support insert with a `VALUES` clause.  You may only insert using another table.  Are you intending to use HQL or a raw SQL query?

Comment: btw after values you can't use =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL Doesn't support Insert with value. So basically use POJO class or follow below link

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html